# How to handle error in event machine using transitions gem on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, event-handling, transition, state-machine

I am working on event machine (transitions gem) in rails 4.2 , I wrote a method named `send_data` and when state changed from pending to deliver, the `send_data` will be fired.

```
def send_data
    data = { 'remote_id' => order.remote_id,
             'items' => order.line_items
           }
    SendLineItemsToWebshop.call(data)        
  end
```

`SendLineItemsToWebshop` is an another class which calls `call` method and waiting for some response, if response come , then event will be fired(state will be changed) , otherwise, state will be same.

```
require 'bunny'
require 'thread'
class SendLineItemsToWebshop
  def self.call(data)
    conn = Bunny.new(automatically_recover: false)
    conn.start
    channel = conn.create_channel
    response = call_client(channel, data)
    channel.queue(ENV['BLISS_RPC_QUEUE_NAME']).pop
    channel.close
    conn.close
    self.response(response)
  end

  def self.call_client(channel, data)
    client = RpcClient.new(channel, ENV['BLISS_RPC_QUEUE_NAME'])
    client.call(data)
  end

  def self.response(response)
    return response
    JSON.parse response
  end
end
```

But problem is that when event `deliver` is called, it does not check `send_data`'s response comes or not, it changes the state. Here is me deliver event:

```
event :deliver do
      transitions :to => :delivered, :from => [:editing, :pending] , on_transition: [ :send_data ]
    end
```

But I want that if response is false or nil, transition state will not be changed. State will be changed only when response comes true.
Please help me about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Transitions gem has a nice `guard` feature. Add a simple logical test like `can_be_delivered?` and try this:

```
event :deliver do
  transitions :to => :delivered, :from => [:editing, :pending], guard: [:can_be_delivered?]
end
```